# how can I pass terminal env COLUMNS and LINES to docker-compose.yml?

Tags: terminal, docker-compose

I want to pass columns size and line size which are defined in my terminal to docker-compose.yml, but it doesn't recognize them if I write like below.

```
environment:
  - COLUMNS=$COLUMNS
  - LINES=$LINES
  - TERM=$TERM
```

And when I hit docker-compose command, it throws the following warning.

```
WARNING: The COLUMNS variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The LINES variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

Has anyone come across this issue and know how to solve this?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You need to ensure those env vars are being passed to `docker-compose`. There are multiple ways of doing this. But you could simply add these variables to a .env file that is automatically loaded by `docker-compose`:

```
COLUMNS=140
LINES=40
TERM=<whichever terminal>
```